# RangeError: Potential infinite loop: exceeded 1500 iterations

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-difference

Hi all I need to return the minimum possible absolute difference. My code is below,

```
function minAbsDiff(nums) {
  const n = nums.length;
  const sum = nums.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);
  const halfSum = Math.floor(sum / 2);
  const dp = Array.from({ length: n+1 }, () => Array.from({ length: sum+1 }, () => false));

  dp[0][0] = true;
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= sum; j++) {
      dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j] || (j >= nums[i-1] ? dp[i-1][j-nums[i-1]] : false);
    }
  }

  let j = halfSum;
  while (!dp[n][j]) j--;
  console.log(sum - 2*j);
}

var x = [2,-1,0,4,-2,-9];
minAbsDiff(x);
```

Here if I give the above x value I got an error:

> RangeError: Potential infinite loop: exceeded 1500 iterations

Other than the above value, I got the result. Help me clear this error.

I tried giving other array values it working fine except the

```
var x = [2,-1,0,4,-2,-9];
```

I need to get difference for it.